# When is exponential map from Lie algebra to Lie group a covering map?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, covering-spaces

Suppose $G$ is a Lie group and $\mathfrak{g}$ its Lie algebra. It is not so difficult to see that if $G$ is abelian and connected then $\exp:\mathfrak{g}\rightarrow G$ is a universal covering map. What if $G$ is non-abelian? Is there a characterization of when $\exp$ is a universal covering map?

Comment: About surjectivity of $\exp$ see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2235973/surjectivity-of-exponential-map-of-a-lie-group?rq=1). More can be found in Terry Tao's [blog](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/06/25/two-small-facts-about-lie-groups/).

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you should assume that $G$ is connected, since otherwise $\exp$ cannot be surjective. Then a complete characterization of Lie connected groups for which $\exp$ is a covering map is given by YCor in his answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/475385/under-what-conditions-is-the-exponential-map-on-a-lie-algebra-injective):

> $\exp$ is a covering map if and only if ${\mathfrak g}$ is solvable and does not contain two particular Lie subalgebras ${\mathfrak e}$, $\tilde{\mathfrak e}$.

The reduction to Yves' answer is easy: $\exp: {\mathfrak g}\to G$ is a covering map if and only if $\exp:  {\mathfrak g}\to \tilde{G}$ is a diffeomorphism, where 
$\tilde{G}$ is the universal covering group of $G$.