# Lie's third theorem (global)

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

[image]

(The image corresponds to the book "Lie Groups, Lie Algebras, and their Representations" by Varadarajan)

Hello. I have a question regarding Lie groups and Lie algebras. If I have a Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ the theorem mentions that there is a  simply connected Lie group $G$ such that its Lie algebra is isomorphic to $\mathfrak{g}$.

**Question 1**.  Is such a group $G$ related to the exponential application? i.e. $G=\left\{\exp(X):X\in\mathcal{G}\right\}$?

Comment: There are several Lie groups with a given Lie algebra and each one has its own exponential map. So you can't talk about **the** exponential map without already specifying the group you mean (the word "application" doesn't really mean anything here, you probably want to say "map" or "function"). Additionally, $\exp$ is rarely surjective so the group won't be the image of $\exp$.

Comment: You are also missing the assumption that the Lie algebra is finite dimensional.

Answer (score 1):

(All Lie algebras are finite-dimensional here.) Generally:

- If $G$ is *any* Lie group with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ then there is an [exponential map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_map_(Lie_theory)) $\exp : \mathfrak{g} \to G$, which can be defined using left-invariant vector fields in general but in the case of matrix Lie groups is the [matrix exponential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential).
- If $G$ is connected, it is generated by the image of the exponential map, because $\exp$ is always a diffeomorphism near the identity and [any connected topological group is generated by an open neighborhood of the identity](https://planetmath.org/connectedtopologicalgroupisgeneratedbyanyneighborhoodofidentity).

These remarks apply in particular to the unique simply connected Lie group with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$. However, generally it's [not true that the exponential map is surjective](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3859971/when-is-the-exponential-map-injective-surjective/3859991#3859991).

**Edit:** Maybe I've misunderstood your question. Maybe you were asking: can one *construct* the unique simply connected Lie group $G$ with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ using the exponential map somehow?

The answer is not obviously yes, since in the absence of a specific Lie group it's not clear what "the exponential map" ought to mean. We can do something like this by first using [Ado's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ado%27s_theorem) to find a faithful representation $\mathfrak{g} \to \mathfrak{gl}(V)$. This means we can apply the ordinary matrix exponential to $\mathfrak{g} \subset \mathfrak{gl}(V)$ which will generate a subgroup of $GL(V)$. This group is not necessarily simply connected, but it does have Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ (this is not obvious but is standard) and we can take its [universal cover](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/UniversalCover.html).

Answer (score 0):

As the comments above already point out, if $G$ is any Lie group with Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$, then there is an exponential map $\text{exp}_G\colon \mathfrak g \to G$ whose image generates $G^0$, the connected component of $G$ containing the identity element of $G$. This map is in general neither injective nor surjective however.

The failure of injectivity is easy to see already for $S^1$ the circle, and it is not too hard to see that the exponential map $\text{exp}\colon \mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb R) \to \mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb R)$ from the Lie algebra  $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb R)= \{X\in \text{Mat}_2(\mathbb R): \text{tr}(X)=0 \}$) to the special linear group $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb R) = \{A\in \text{Mat}_2(\mathbb R): \det(A)=1\}$ which is given by $\text{exp}(X) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{X^k}{k!}$ is not surjective.

None of the above involves the fundamental group of $G$ however. Where the issue of simple-connectedness *does* naturally arise in the context of Lie's theorems, is when one asks about homomorphisms: if $\phi\colon \mathfrak g\to \mathfrak h$ is a Lie algebra homomorphism, and $\mathfrak g = \text{Lie}(G)$, $\mathfrak h = \text{Lie}(H)$, then it is natural to ask if one can "integrate" $\phi$ to a homomorphism of Lie groups $\Phi\colon G \to H$, such that
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\mathfrak{g} @>{\phi}>> \mathfrak h\\
@V{\exp_G}VV @VV{\exp_H}V\\
G @>{\Phi ?}>> H
\end{CD}
$$
Now since $\exp\colon \mathfrak g\to G$ is locally a diffeomorphism from $0_{\mathfrak g}$ to $e_G$ and the exponential of a derivation is a homomorphism, one expects $\phi$ to "locally lift" to a homomorphism from $G$ to $H$ -- indeed it must be given by $\exp_H(\phi(\log_G(g))$ where $\log$ is a local inverse to $\exp_G$ at $e_G$ -- but in general the ability to lift locally will not ensure the existence of a globally defined homomorphism from $G$ to $H$. Perhaps the simplest example of this global failure is given by taking $G=S^1$ and $H= \mathbb R$ -- then  $\mathfrak g = \mathrm{Lie}(G)=\mathrm{Lie}(H) = \mathfrak h$,  with both being equal to  $\mathfrak{gl}_1(\mathbb R)$, that is, the real numbers as a Lie algebra with the zero Lie bracket. It follows that we have an obvious homomorphism from $\phi\colon \mathfrak g \to \mathfrak h$ given by the identity map, but there is no corresponding homomorphism $\Phi\colon S^1\to \mathbb R$ for it to integrate to (the image of $S^1$ under a continuous map will be compact, but $(\mathbb R,+)$ has no compact subgroups other than the trivial subgroup, hence the only continuous homomorphism from $S^1$ to $\mathbb R$ is the constant map to $0_{\mathbb R}$. On the other hand, if we let $G$ and $H$ trade places, then the exponential map itself gives the lift of $\phi^{-1}$ to a homomorphism of groups from $\mathbb R$ to $S^1$.

The crucial difference between the two groups turns out to be the fact that $\mathbb R$ is simply connected: whenever $G$ is simply connected, using the fact that a path can then be lifted from $\mathfrak g$ to $G$ uniquely up to homotopy, one can show that any $\phi\colon \mathfrak g\to \mathfrak h$ lifts to a group homomorphism $\Phi\colon G \to H$. (Note that, as we saw in the example of $\mathbb R^1$ and $S^1$, the group $H$ is not required to be simply-connected here, only $G$.)